# ViewSwitcher and a custom-animated ImageView

Tags: android, animation, view

I would like to to implement some RotatingImageView and I have an animation looking like this:

```
public void init() {

    mCurrentRotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.51f);
    mCurrentRotateAnimation.setDuration(0);
    mCurrentRotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    mCurrentRotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    mCurrentRotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new InfoInterpolator());
    startAnimation(mCurrentRotateAnimation);
}
```

The difficulty appeared when this RotatingImageView started to be used in a ViewSwitcher (which is a [ViewAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html)) and that ViewSwitcher changes himself the animation depending on the in/out animation it has (basically by calling startAnimation() with his own in/out animation, **which overrides my rotating animation**:

```
// ViewSwitcher/ViewAnimator code changing the animation    
void showOnly(int childIndex, boolean animate) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (i == childIndex) {
            if (animate && mInAnimation != null) {
                child.startAnimation(mInAnimation);
            }
            child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mFirstTime = false;
        } else {
            if (animate && mOutAnimation != null && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                child.startAnimation(mOutAnimation);
            } else if (child.getAnimation() == mInAnimation)
                child.clearAnimation();
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried by retaining the input of a fake Interpolator to "know" where the rotating animation stopped and restore it when startAnimation is recalled by the ViewSwitcher, but there's still a "jump" in the rotating animation!

How can I make an ImageView rotating all the time and add and remove the correct in/out animation that comes from the ViewSwitcher/ViewAnimator **without stopping the rotating animation**?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you using the `ImageView` as a direct child of the `ViewSwitcher`?

Comment: Yes indeed... hooo that's a good idea...

Comment: Try wrapping it in another layout, like a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Yeah I got it on your first comment! :) The two animations are working now and I hoped it'll be perfect but the ImageView (the rotated one) blinks at the beginning of the rotation), any idea why? (I wrapped it at first in a LinearLayout then tried FrameLayout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animated view will always blink if you use the old animation system while changing its visibility trough a ViewSwitcher.
The solution is to use a ViewPropertyAnimator which will actually modify the properties of the view, and this is why your view will retain its position ( here its angle ) even after being hidden by the viewSwitcher.

Here is an example based on your RotatingImageView, if you are targeting android < 11 you should be using [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids).

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void init() {
    ObjectAnimator rotationAnimator = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(), R.animator.rotation);
    rotationAnimator.setTarget(this);
    rotationAnimator.start();
}
```

And here is the rotation.xml (to be placed in res/animator)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:valueTo="360"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```